# Adding new relationship to the existing array of relationship

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have array of relationship in one of my asset.

`asset Patient identified by medicalRecordNumber {
    --> LabReports[] labReports optional
    }`

In a transaction im trying to add new relationship in the array labReports. But its giving me error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Here is my logic.js code

```
    var patientId = searchPatient[0].medicalRecordNumber;
    var patientRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.zcon.healthcare.Patient');
    var patientObj = await patientRegistry.get(patientId);

    var labreports=[];
    labreports=patientObj.labReports;
    var newLabReport =factory.newResource('org.zcon.healthcare', 'LabReports', labReportFromattedId); 
    labreports.push(newLabReport);
    patientObj.labReports=labreports;

    await patientRegistry.update(patientObj);
```

How to update the asset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially you don't have any `labReports` for `patientObj` therefore It's undefined and when you try to access `push` method of `undefined` property, it throws error.

Try the below solution, It should work

```js
var patientId = searchPatient[0].medicalRecordNumber;
var patientRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.zcon.healthcare.Patient');
var patientObj = await patientRegistry.get(patientId);

if(typeof patientObj.labReports !== 'object' || patientObj.labReports.constructor !== Array) {
    patientObj.labReports = [];
}

var newLabReport = factory.newResource('org.zcon.healthcare', 'LabReports', labReportFromattedId); 
patientObj.labReports.push(newLabReport);
await patientRegistry.update(patientObj);
```